# 'any' vs 'Object'

Tags: typescript

I am looking at TypeScript code and noticed that they use:

```
interface Blablabla {

   field: Object;

}
```

What is the benefit of using `Object` vs `any`, as in:

```
interface Blablabla {

  field: any;

}
```

Answer (score 238, accepted):

`Object` is more restrictive than `any`. For example:

```
let a: any;
let b: Object;

a.nomethod(); // Transpiles just fine
b.nomethod(); // Error: Property 'nomethod' does not exist on type 'Object'.
```

The `Object` class does not have a `nomethod()` function, therefore the transpiler will generate an error telling you exactly that. If you use `any` instead you are basically telling the transpiler that anything goes, you are providing no information about what is stored in `a` - it can be anything! And therefore the transpiler will allow you to do whatever you want with something defined as `any`.

So in short

- `any` can be anything (you can call any method etc on it without compilation errors)
- `Object` exposes the functions and properties defined in the `Object` class.

Answer (score 389):

Bit old, but doesn't hurt to add some notes.

When you write something like this

```
let a: any;
let b: Object;
let c: {};
```

- **a** has no interface, it can be anything, the compiler knows nothing about its members so no type checking is performed when accessing/assigning both to it and its members. Basically, you're telling the compiler to "*back off, I know what I'm doing, so just trust me*";
- **b** has the Object interface, so ONLY the members defined in that interface are available for **b**. It's still JavaScript, so everything extends Object;
- **c** extends Object, like anything else in TypeScript, but adds no members. Since type compatibility in TypeScript is based on structural subtyping, not nominal subtyping, **c** ends up being the same as **b** because they have the same interface: the Object interface.

And that's why

```
a.doSomething(); // Ok: the compiler trusts you on that
b.doSomething(); // Error: Object has no doSomething member
c.doSomething(); // Error: c neither has doSomething nor inherits it from Object
```

and why

```
a.toString(); // Ok: whatever, dude, have it your way
b.toString(); // Ok: toString is defined in Object
c.toString(); // Ok: c inherits toString from Object
```

So `Object` and `{}` are equivalents in TypeScript.

If you declare functions like these

```
function fa(param: any): void {}
function fb(param: Object): void {}
```

with the intention of accepting anything for param (maybe you're going to check types at run-time to decide what to do with it), remember that

- inside **fa**, the compiler will let you do whatever you want with **param**;
- inside **fb**, the compiler will only let you reference **Object**'s members.

It is worth noting, though, that if **param** is supposed to accept multiple known types, a better approach is to declare it using union types, as in

```
function fc(param: string|number): void {}
```

Obviously, OO inheritance rules still apply, so if you want to accept instances of derived classes and treat them based on their base type, as in

```
interface IPerson {
    gender: string;
}

class Person implements IPerson {
    gender: string;
}

class Teacher extends Person {}

function func(person: IPerson): void {
    console.log(person.gender);
}

func(new Person());     // Ok
func(new Teacher());    // Ok
func({gender: 'male'}); // Ok
func({name: 'male'});   // Error: no gender..
```

the base type is the way to do it, not **any**. But that's OO, out of scope, I just wanted to clarify that **any** should only be used when you don't know whats coming, and for anything else you should annotate the correct type.

UPDATE:

[Typescript 2.2](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-2.html) added an `object` type, which specifies that a value is a non-primitive: (i.e. not a `number`, `string`, `boolean`, `symbol`, `undefined`, or `null`).

Consider functions defined as:

```
function b(x: Object) {}
function c(x: {}) {}
function d(x: object) {}
```

`x` will have the same available properties within all of these functions, but it's a type error to call `d` with a primitive:

```
b("foo"); //Okay
c("foo"); //Okay
d("foo"); //Error: "foo" is a primitive
```

Comment: Does anybody know *why* they decided to add `{}` then if they already had `Object`? (or vice versa, whichever came first) There's got to be some slight difference, right?

Comment: `{}` is the normal way to define (inline) interfaces, only that in this case you are defining an interface with no members. The slight difference is well explained in the response: "`{}` extends `Object`, like anything else in TypeScript".

Comment: I want to down vote you for the line _So, basically, when you don't know the type, go with `any` and do run-time type checking._ Don't use `any`, instead use a union of the types you are checking against: `TypeA|InterfaceB|string`. If you also have a default case for an unknown type, add either `{}` or `Object` to the union.

Comment: Typescript docs are sometimes confusing, for example `But variables of type Object only allow you to assign any value to them - you can’t call arbitrary methods on them, even ones that actually exist:` made me think that even calling `toString` is not allowed, when in fact I think they meant to say `exist at runtime` after reading you answer.

Comment: I landed here because I wanted to know how to declare that a parameter should be an object with key, value pairs. This can be achieved by `parameter: {[key: string]: any}`

Comment: basically, with `any`, the compiler just gives up and let you do anything. I both love and hate this kind of stuff for the same reasons...

Answer (score 26):

`any` is something specific to TypeScript is explained quite well by alex's answer.

`Object` refers to the JavaScript `object` type. Commonly used as `{}` or sometimes `new Object`. Most things in *javascript* are compatible with the object data type as they inherit from it. But `any` is *TypeScript* specific and compatible with everything in both directions (not inheritance based). e.g. :

```
var foo:Object; 
var bar:any;
var num:number;

foo = num; // Not an error
num = foo; // ERROR 

// Any is compatible both ways 
bar = num;
num = bar;
```

Comment: Your answer is quite vague and mixes `Object` and `object` which are different types in TypeScript.

Comment: @m93a: Can you expand on what is the difference between `Object` and `object` in TS?

Comment: [This](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2017/02/24/typescript-2-2-the-object-type#object-vs-object-vs) is probably the best source to learn the difference. The main point is that `object` is a type for everything that is not primitive, while `Object` is an interface that contains common things like `toString` and such. The number `42` would be an `Object` but not an `object`.

Answer (score 22):

Contrary to .NET where all types derive from an "object", in TypeScript, all types derive from "any". I just wanted to add this comparison as I think it will be a common one made as more .NET developers give TypeScript a try.

Answer (score 19):

Object appears to be a more specific declaration than any. From the TypeScript spec (section 3):

> All types in TypeScript are subtypes of a single top type called the
>   Any type. The any keyword references  this type. The Any type is the
>   one type that can represent any JavaScript value with no constraints.
>   All  other types are categorized as primitive types, object types, or
>   type parameters. These types introduce  various static constraints on
>   their values.

Also:

> The Any type is used to represent any JavaScript value. A value of the
>   Any type supports the same  operations as a value in JavaScript and
>   minimal static type checking is performed for operations on Any 
>   values. Specifically, properties of any name can be accessed through
>   an Any value and Any values can be  called as functions or
>   constructors with any argument list.

Objects do not allow the same flexibility.

For example:

```
var myAny : any;

myAny.Something(); // no problemo

var myObject : Object;

myObject.Something(); // Error: The property 'Something' does not exist on value of type 'Object'.
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Alex's answer and simplifying it:

Objects are more strict with their use and hence gives the programmer more compile time "evaluation" power and hence in a lot of cases provide more "checking capability" and coould prevent any leaks, whereas any is a more generic term and a lot of compile time checks might hence be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

If your data has more than one key and value pair than you must have to use object
because any accept any kind of data which means some case its not better.
for example if you are performing addition of two number means data must be specify as number datatype if u specify string then i will not perform proper addition.
most probably we don't use the any

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).