# Different return types on inherited classes

Tags: javascript, class, typescript, interface, callback

Say I have classes A and B. A defines all the stuff that B may use. A has no idea, what type some callback parameter may have when used by B. So in A they are defined as Object.

```
class A {

    private _on_user_selection:(selection:Object) => void = $.noop;

    set on_user_selection(fn:(selection:Object) => void) {
        if ($.isFunction(fn)) {
            this._on_user_selection = fn;
        }
    }
}

class B extends A {
    // ...
}
```

B knows what to expect as callback param. Now what would I have to do in B, so that I can use it like this:

```
let b = new B();
b.on_user_selection = (selection:SomeInterfaceDefindeSomewhere):void => {
    // ...
};
```

In this case the above would work just fine, but I want to fix the callback return type within B, not only where its actually called.

Comment: Wont override work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make `A` generic:

```
class A<T> {
    private _on_user_selection: (selection: T) => void = $.noop;

    set on_user_selection(fn: (selection: T) => void) {
        if ($.isFunction(fn)) {
            this._on_user_selection = fn;
        }
    }
}

class B extends A<SomeInterfaceDefindeSomewhere> {
    // ...
}
```

Also, do not use type `Object`, [instead use `any`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18961203/typescript-any-vs-object) or the [new `object` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-2.html#object-type).

Comment: Great, exactly what I was looking for! Thanks :)