# Can't access response elements in Angular 2 http request

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-http

I have the code for interface

```
export interface Books {
  artists: any;
  tracks: any;
}
```

And I m using this interface in service for getting search results.

```
getBook(keyword): Observable<Books>{
   let headers = new Headers();
   this.createAuthorizationHeader(headers);
    return this._http.get('https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=' + keyword + '&type=track,artist', {
    headers: headers
   })
  .map((response: Response) => <Books> response.json());
}
```

After getting results I want to show this in the component

```
getBooks(value) {
  this._search.getBook(value)
  .subscribe(
  res => {
    this.books = res;
    this.artists = Object.assign({}, res.artists);
    console.log(this.artists);
  },
  error => { this.errMessage = <any>error }
  );
}
```

The response looks like

```
{
 href: "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?query=muse&type=artist&market=US&offset=0&limit=20",
 items: [list of objects],
 limit: 20,
 total: 159,
}
```

In **console.log(this.artists)** I am getting the above object but when I am trying to access its items in **console.log(this.artists.items);** it gives me this error.

```
Property 'items' does not exist on type 'Object'
```

Any idea whats I am missing ???

Comment: can you please give the actual response object. I think there might be some issue with the response object. It may not be in the correct format.

Comment: Below the first console.
    console.log(this.artists);

Comment: @echonax it prints Object.

Comment: Maybe try `console.log((<any>this.artists).items);`?  The `artists` is defined as `any` in the interface.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeScript any vs Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18961203/typescript-any-vs-object)

Comment: @echonax this error comes in console.

Comment: @echonax yeah console.log((<any>this.artists).items); this worked for me, thanks.