# Angular Observable map system

Tags: angular

How can i get value on observable->Map, because i already got error:
 Property 'target' does not exist on type '{}'

```
import { Component , ViewChild , AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    template: `<h1>Hello World!</h1>
                <input type="text" #name >
                `,


})

export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit { 
@ViewChild ('name') input;


ngAfterViewInit(){
    var keyup = Observable.fromEvent(this.input.nativeElement,"keyup")
                          .map(data => data.target.value);
    keyup.subscribe(data => console.log(data));
}
}
```

Comment: Try `.map( (data: any) => data.target.value);`

Comment: echonax's suggestion should be an acceptable workaround, though 'better' (with stronger typing) exist, see https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/1822

Comment: thanks for your fast reply and its already solved but i wonder whats wrong with my code ?!

Comment: thanks echonax i got that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid this error with

```
.map( (data: any) => data.target.value);
```

or as @Pac0 stated, you can create an interface/type for your actualy object.

The `map` operators default type for its values is `Object` as it seems.

You can find more info about the difference between `any` and `Object` here: [TypeScript any vs Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18961203/typescript-any-vs-object)