# Angular export import object (getting object data)

Tags: javascript, module, ecmascript-6

On file 'A' I have this:

```
export const settings: object = {
  base: 1
}
```

Now on file 'B' I import it and extract the base value:

```
import * as mySettings from '../settings';

baseValue: object=mySettings.settings.base;
```

This is returning an error:

property: base does not exist on type: object.

How can I fix this?

Comment: You could give it a type that includes the base property, specifically (`{ base: number }`) or generally (`{ [key: string]: number }`). Or just `any`, but then you might as well not use TS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeScript any vs Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18961203/typescript-any-vs-object)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Solution

Remove the type in your code, in this case the word "object"

## Results

**Creating the Settings File**

Create a file with following code, let's save with the name `settings`

```
export const settings = {
  base: 1
};
```

**Importing the file**

Now, import the file with the path `'../settings'`, I created a alias `mySettings`

```
import * as mySettings from '../settings';

baseValue: number = mySettings.settings.base;
```