# Type Object is not generic when making build using ng build --prod

Tags: angular, typescript

I have following declaration in my component class
    formErrors:Object;

while using ng build --prod, it throws
 Type 'Object' is not generic.

but every things working in run time compilation, using ng serve

and i have used the formErrors as below in my template

```html
   <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 form-group has-feedback required" [ngClass]="{'has-error':formErrors?.country}">
          <input class="form-control has-feedback-left" name="country" [(ngModel)]="customer.country" placeholder="Country" type="text">
          <span class="fa fa-map-marker form-control-feedback left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="help-block" *ngIf="formErrors?.country">{{formErrors?.country[0]}}</span>
        </div>
```

Comment: Give us one example of you using `formErrors` in the template

Comment: Maybe use `any` instead of `Object`? Check out this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18961203/typescript-any-vs-object

Comment: sorry, it was my mistake i put small portion of form input above and the actually the error was produced from another field where i left to place '?'