# What does the <{}> mean in react class?

Tags: typescript, react-native, ecmascript-6

Haven't been touching RN for a while, it still remains at ES6 syntax.

Then I saw `export default class App extends Component<{}> {` and started wondering what does the <{}> means, anyone can help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's probably related to the type (TypeScript) and the `{}` represents the type used for props. Check out this SO answer - [TypeScript any vs Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18961203/typescript-any-vs-object)

Looking at the source code for [React types](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts) `interface Component<P = {}, S = {}> extends ComponentLifecycle<P, S> { }` type P is type for props and S is type related to state of component.

Answer (score 1):

**Flow**
It relate flow typing for the props - https://flow.org/en/docs/react/components/

`<{}>`  is the definition of an empty object, indicating there are no additional properties for the component.

**REFERENCE**
[React-Native Feature Request](https://react-native.canny.io/feature-requests/p/kindly-add-what-does-this-symbol-refer)