# on ng build --prod am gettng error,Property 'email' does not exist on type 'Object

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, angular2-forms, ng-build

declared loginObj in login.component.ts as below

```
 public loginObj: Object = {
   email:'',
   password:''
 };
 public registerObj: Object = {
  email:'',
  name:'',
  password:''
 };
```

HTML

```
<input placeholder="" type="text"  [(ngModel)]="loginObj.email" autofocus="true" required>
<input placeholder="" type="text"  [(ngModel)]="loginObj.password" autofocus="true" required>
```

Comment: Replace `: Object` with `: any`.

Comment: you might find this answer helpful to explain why you cannot use `Object` in this way https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18961203/typescript-any-vs-object#28795689
use `object` or as answered below, create an interface with a unique name

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make the type any instead of Object or define an interface and make it the type.

Answer (score 6):

The error is right this property is not existing. You need to create interface

```
export interface LoginObject {
   email:string;
   password:string;
}
```

adn then import it into your component and declare your object like this

```
public loginObj: LoginObject = {
   email:'',
   password:''
 };
```

You can even try to declare it just like this

```
public loginObj: LoginObject;
```

and it will work for you

Comment: Thanks, it really helps me.

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar error while building it in jenkins. The following command resolved the issue:

```
npm install
npm run ng build --prod
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I believe this build command is not doing a production build and is acting as if you are running 'ng build' which still loads all the dev dependencies.

Comment: @RobDePietro I think you might be right. I ran this command in GCP cloud build and sure enough I was always getting the "Angular is running in development mode" console message.

Answer (score 0):

try add this dependencies in your package.json
"@angular/compiler-cli":"9.0.0 (or other version you used)"