# Why is this allowed in typescript?

Tags: typescript

Why does typescript allows this code ?

```
class Test<T> {
    private value: T;
    public setValue(value: T): this {
        this.value = value;
        return this;
    }
}

const test = new Test();
test.setValue(5);
```

As i instantiate the generic `Test` class without specifying the generic argument, the `test` variable is of type `Test<{}>`.

I thought that `{}` was an empty type, how can it be assigned a `number` ?

Thanks

Comment: Essentially what's being asked is why `const t: {} = 5;` does not result in a compile error. See the linked to question for the answer.

Comment: Thank you, does this mean that `{}` is the same as `any` ? I mean i wouldn't expect `{}` to be structurally compliant with a `number`.

Comment: No. One example: `any` is assignable to `number` (`const t: number = 5 as any;`), but `{}` is not assignable to `number` (`const t: number = 5 as {};`--compile error). Read more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18961203/any-vs-object

Comment: That's more clear, thanks. The second link proved to be very helpful.