# "{}" as type in Typescript

Tags: typescript

What type is a variable declared as below. In what case is it useful?

```
let x: {}
```

In the following type alias what is the meaning of `{}`. Is it equivalent to `object` or `any`? Why you would want to use `{}` as type instead of `any`? Does `{}`, in this case mean "instance" of empty object? (does make sense to me)

```
type MessageHandler<D, P> = (data: D, payload: P) => void
type MessageHandlerGeneric = MessageHandler<{}, any}

interface MessageHandlers {
  [index: string]: MessageHandlerGeneric
}

let handlers = MessageHandlers = {
  handler1: (data: string, payload: Pyaload),
  handler2: (data: Array<string>, payload: Payload)
}
```

Comment: you might want to correct the typo: `Pyaload`  :-)

Comment: `{}` is an object, isn't it? `any` means anything; an object, a number, a string, `undefined`, an array etc. Why do you think that `{}` is the same thing as `any`?

Comment: I think you should check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18961203/any-vs-object

Comment: As I understand it `any` also could be `undefined` or `null`. So `object` and `any` are similar to me except that the compiler doesn't perform type checks for `any`. Am I wrong?

Comment: The `Object` (with capital O) mainly describes that the object has the common javascript methods like `toString`

Comment: Relevant isue on TypeScript's github : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8032

Comment: `any` has no restrictions it can be anything, but `{}` has restrictions like an object it only allows you to access to members.

Answer (score 0):

`Object` is more restrictive than `any`.

```
const b: Object = {};
b.myMethod();
```

won't compile (where `myMethod()` is not declared and known method). On the other hand, the method below compiles.

```
const c: any = {};
c.myMethod();
```

So, `any` can be anything (including `null`/`undefined`) on the other hand, If you explicitly use `Object` you will only be able to use the properties that are defined on the `Object` class.

Answer (score 0):

As others pointed out - once variable typed as `any`, compiler won't warn you if you'll try to access non existing properties or assign **any** value.

Regarding `object` vs `{}` - `object` is a type that represents the non-primitive type, i.e. any thing that is not `number` | `string` | `boolean` | `symbol`.

```
const foo: object = 'test'; // error 
const bar: {} = 'test'; // ok
```