# in TS, How to define children property?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mobx

I am studying `Typescript` with `React` and `MobX`.

My `MobX` Store likes blew.

```
store: {
  child: {
    selected: true,
    value: 123
  }
}
```

My Component is

```
@inject('store')
@observer
class Display extends React.Component<{store: Object}, {}> {
  ...

  render(){
    console.log(this.props.store.child.selected); // true
  }
}
```

and I can see this alert.

> [ts] Property 'child' does not exist on type 'Object'. [2339]

Comment: I think you are looking for  `class Display extends React.Component<{store:  child: {
    selected: boolean,
    value: number
  }
}, {}>`

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Oh... is it the only way to solve it?

Comment: `store: any` would be the other but that basically breaks out of type safety altogether and I don't recommend it

Comment: It is actually very logical. `Object` type doesn't have `child` property inside it. To make it work, you could define your type more explicitly, or just pass `store: any` (but please don't, I assume you are not using TypeScript to ignore typing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use interfaces to declare the shapes of store:

```
interface Child {
    selected: boolean;
    value: number;
}

interface Store {
    child: Child;
}

@inject('store')
@observer
class Display extends React.Component<{ store: Store }, {}> {
  ...

  render() {
    console.log(this.props.store.child.selected); // true
  }
}
```

Or you can use either [`any`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18961203/any-vs-object) or [`unknown`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51439843/typescript-3-0-unknown-vs-any) for the store type.

Answer (score 2):

The error you're getting is because you're defining your store prop as a generic `Object`, which doesn't have a property called `child`.

To make it work, just define an interface for your store like so:

```
interface Store {
  store: {
    child: {
      selected: boolean;
      value: number;
    }
  }
}
```

And then use that as definition for the props in the component as such:

`class Display extends React.Component<Store, {}> {`