# Disadvantages of any keyword

Tags: typescript

I am using `any` instead of its data-type (String or Array).

just like this:

```
token: any
```

**Instead of**

```
token: String
```

Can anyone tell me what is the difference between both and which is best to use `data-type` or `any`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18961904/7541317

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only difference is that if you use `token: any`, you don't get the benefit of type checking that helps you debug your code and prevents you from doing things like assigning a number to your `token: String`.