# Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type '{}' has no index signature error when using object originating from fetched JSON

Tags: json, typescript

I'm trying to compile my TypeScript code to JavaScript, but in doing so I get a bunch of errors saying `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type '{}' has no index signature`. There occur when I access an object originating from JSON fetched via `fetch()` and the `noImplicitAny` compiler option is set to true.

Here is some sample code that triggers the issue on compile:

index.js:

```
class Foobar {
    constructor(data: object) {
        console.log(data[0].mapScale);
    }
}

getMapObject()
    .then(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        new Foobar(data);
    });

function getMapObject() {
    return fetch("/map.json")
        .then(response => response.json());
}
```

map.json:

```
[{"mapScale": 10}]
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "noImplicitAny": true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you specified an `object` type, which doesn't give much info about the data structure. If you aren't going to use specific typing, you can still use `object` or `any` types, but if you are, you should use types/interfaces for that, and specify returning values as well, something like this:

```
interface IItem {
  mapScale: number;
}

class Foobar {
  constructor(data: IItem[]) {
    console.log(data[0].mapScale);
  }
}

getMapObject()
  .then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    new Foobar(data);
  });

function getMapObject(): Promise<IItem[]> {
  return fetch('/map.json')
    .then(response => response.json());
}
```

You can also take a look at this post, to learn more about the `object` and `any` types: ['any' vs 'Object'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18961203/any-vs-object).