# Why is strong type lost with `any` in typescript?

Tags: typescript

Can someone explain why the following typescript can't catch the typing problem?

```js
function z(a: number) {
    console.log(a*a);
}

z(1); // works
z("xyz"); // fails type checking

function y(a: any){
    z(a); // I expect this statement to be erroneous
}

y(1); // works
y("xyz"); // does not fail type checking; feels like duck-typing?
```

In the example above, the compiler knows that y is being passed a `string` and therefore `z` is being passed a string. This should be sufficient for a transpiler error. Could someone explain the decisions that went into the transpiler design?

Thank you! :)

Comment: My assumption is, since `any` supersets everything, it passes the check. A guess though

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Any vs Other Types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18961203/7124761)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In `y`, `a` has any form, so it's a valid `number`, `any` is as a very permissive object, but in the case you might want to say, i don't know what `a` is, therefore i might want to perform some checks before calling `z` then you should use `unknown` as the least permissive type.

```js
function y(a: unknown){
  z(a); // Argument of type 'unknown' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.ts(2345)
  if (typeof a === 'number') {
    z(a) // all good
  }
}
```

`any` is there for compatibility with existing javascript code or to escape safety, as of typescript 3.0 `unknown` is the go to type when not sure what type we're dealing with, forcing to narrow the type first. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#new-unknown-top-type

Answer (score 1):

> Can someone explain why the following typescript can't catch the typing problem?

```
y("xyz"); // does not fail type checking; feels like duck-typing?
```

Ok so what is the signature of the method `y`?

```
function y(a: any)
```

Is `"xyz"` a valid `any`?  Yes it is.  That being said, `a` is now of type `any`, not of type `string`.  You've explicitly told the compiler that it's `any` not `string` so since `any` could be a `number` the call is valid.

In this regard, the typescript team simply decided to not do any type checking on any because Javascript allows this type of behavior and the typescript team wanted to extend/enhance javascript not prevent you from doing something if you wanted to.  `any` is an op-in feature and you can turn off implicitAny using the typescript compiler arguments (or tsconfig.json).