# Typescript: when would you use 'unknown' vs. 'object'?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I am still rather new to TypeScript and trying to work on my knowledge and intuition about when to use which types.

When would you use `unknown` vs. `object`?

From https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html:

#### About `object`:

> `object` is a type that represents the non-primitive type, i.e. anything that is not `number`, `string`, `boolean`, `symbol`, `null`, or `undefined`.

#### About `unknown`:

> We may need to describe the type of variables that we do not know when we are writing an application. These values may come from dynamic content – e.g. from the user – or we may want to intentionally accept all values in our API. In these cases, we want to provide a type that tells the compiler and future readers that this variable could be anything, so we give it the `unknown` type.

Is `unknown` a strict superset of `object`?

Is `unknown` maybe precisely `object` + `number` + `string` + `boolean` + `symbol` + `null` + `undefined`? If not: what's missing -- precisely, or conceptually?

If the TypeScript version matters for answering this: let's assume 3.9 :-).

Comment: I don't know if I had ever a use for `object`. I'd rather be either more or less specific. Plus, `object` includes functions, which I usually want to treat differently. About `unknown`, I've not had much experience with that one either, The cases from your description, there I usually use `any` but that may be just an old habit. Have to look into that.

Comment: ESLint says: "Don't use `object` as a type. The `object` type is currently hard to use. See https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21732. Consider using `Record<string, unknown>` instead, as it allows you to more easily inspect and use the keys".

Comment: By the way, somewhat related discussion about any vs Object (capital O): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18961203/any-vs-object -- but that somehow seems to be pretty out of date.

Comment: Consider: `const x: unknown = {}` vs `const y: object = {}` where `x.bla()` would be denied by the compiler as it's unknown. `y.bla()` would only be denied as bla is not defined on type object. In general you should avoid to denote a variable/parameter etc with type object, as it can cause confusion.

Answer (score 3):

Don't mix together these two types. The `object` is kinda "real" type, it exists in runtime, it allows you to deal with instances of the Object. I would say it's just regular, normal type.

But `unknown` is a kinda different thing. It was created to guard operations with types that don't have a type at all. It denies any direct operations with this type:

```
const x:unknown = 5;
x+= 1; // Object is of type 'unknown'.
```

It also not exists in runtime, so you can't create an instance of unknown or something like this.

So, I would say that unknown is the opposite type to any defined type.

Comment: Typescript types don't exist in runtime.

Comment: @Sander did I state something else? If you talking about the "object" - I meant that `object` type represents `Object` which, of course exists in runtume